# Extracting data values belonging to a day and compute average value to each day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frequency, series

I have a dataset with a date range from January 12th to August 3rd 2018 with some values:

[image]

The dimensionality of `df_luminosidad` DataFrame is:

```
df_luminosidad.shape
(9752, 2)
```

Each row of data has a half-hour frequency. The first row begins at `2018-01-12`

```
df_luminosidad.iloc[0]

Fecha:       2018-01-12 00:17:28
Luz (lux)                      1
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

And the last row ends at `2018-08-03`

```
df_luminosidad.tail(1)

Fecha:  Luz (lux)
9751    2018-08-03 23:44:59 1
```

There are many rows which correspond to one day such as denoted above.

I want to create a new dataframe selecting only 1 day as a value for the `Fecha:` column (no a repeated date) and select the average value from all existing value for the selected date of the `Luz(lux) column`

This would look like this:

```
|  Fecha:     |  Luz(lux) - Average each day values |
|  2018-01-12 |  9183.479167                        |
|  2018-01-13 |  7431.8125                          |
|  2018-01-14 |  11073.1875                         |
|  2018-01-15 |  11456.25                           |
|      .             .                              |
|      .             .                              |
|      .             .                              |
|  2018-08-03 |  11331.229167                       |
```

I am using `pd.date_range()` function to create a dataframe with the values from  `df_luminosidad` previous dataframe to a specified frequency such as denoted [@piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared) [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52265394/2773461)

From January 12 to August 03 there are 203 days (28 weeks), then I choose 204 like `period` attribute, and I am using a `freq` attribute calendar day frequency `D`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Date=pd.date_range('2018-01-12', periods=204, freq='D'),
    Value=df_luminosidad['Luz (lux)'].mean()   
))
```

Until here, the approach is well, but I have a doubt about of how to compute the mean of `Luz (lux)` values to each day selected with `pd.date_range`, because, at this moment I just get an average same value for all days from  `2018-01-12` until `2018-08-03` such as follow:

```
|  Date       |  Value        |
|  2018-01-12 |  11228.888331 |                       
|  2018-01-13 |  11228.888331 |                         
|  2018-01-14 |  11228.888331 |                        
|  2018-01-15 |  11228.888331 |                          
|      .             .        |                      
|      .             .        |                      
|      .             .        |                      
|  2018-08-03 |  11331.229167 |
```

I've already generated a dataframe by each `Fecha:` column values, and separately I could get their average, but this force me to read
each file day individually.

How can I generate of a cyclic way grouping all values of a day into a only average value by each day and put them in one dataframe?

Comment: post a sample df and expected output df, not image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `mean` or aggregate `mean` with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df_luminosidad['Fecha:'] = pd.to_datetime(df_luminosidad['Fecha:'])

df = df_luminosidad.resample('D', on='Fecha:')['Luz (lux)'].mean().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df = (df_luminosidad.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Fecha:', freq='D'))['Luz (lux)']
                    .mean()
                    .reset_index())
```

Another solutions with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df_luminosidad['Fecha:'] = pd.to_datetime(df_luminosidad['Fecha:'])
df_luminosidad = df_luminosidad.set_index('Fecha:')


df = df_luminosidad.resample('D')['Luz (lux)'].mean().reset_index()
df = df_luminosidad.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))['Luz (lux)'].mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: Great, but with one or other alternatives I get this error message `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`

Comment: @bgarcial -Waht is `print (df_luminosidad['Fecha:'].dtype)`  ?

Comment: If not datetime, need `df_luminosidad['Fecha:'] = pd.to_datetime(df_luminosidad['Fecha:'])`

Answer (score 2):

For time series analysis,first convert your date column as index, if possible, and after that it's convenient to use with dates.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', parse_dates =['Fecha'], index_col='Fecha')
```

Then you can fetch any date value into another temporary dataframe.

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-12 ', end='2018-08-03 ')
```

Now using for loop, rander each date from 'dates' list and then select the required portion of your dataset into another dataframe.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()   # Creating temporary data frame to store each day value
for temp_date in dates:
    required_date = str(temp_date)[:10]     # this is to fetch only date value from whole time stamp
    new_df = df1[required_date]  
# Now our requrired data is in new dataframe, and we can do all things to our new dataframe.
```

It might be suggesting a naive method, but right now I have this much suggestion for you. Hope it works.